# SQLiteDatabase on a null object reference

Tags: android, database, nullpointerexception

Supposedly, I wanted to call a SQLStatement, which eventually will return a ID for a particular row.

```
public int FindInDatabase(String info){

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT id FROM " + DatabaseName + " WHERE " + DataField + " = " + info,null);
        if (c != null){
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c.getInt(1);
    }
```

Above code cannot be executed successfully, it contains error of Cursor: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])`
on a null object reference . What is wrong overhere? Thanks.

Comment: Are you initializing `db` properly?

Comment: You need to initialise open database before calling query have you done it in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In class where you have extended **SqliteOpenHelper**. Intialize **db** object before using it.

```
public int FindInDatabase(String info){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT id FROM " + DatabaseName + " WHERE " + DataField + " = " + info,null);
        if (c != null){
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c.getInt(1);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I got an error of cannot resolve method 'getReadbleDatabse()' .. How to fix this?tq

Comment: @JackPowell okay. In which class you have this method FindInDatabase(). Is it in Activity? or class which extended SqliteOpenHelper.?

Comment: This method "FindInDatabase()" was implemented in the activity class. The activity class is not extended with SqliteOpenHelper. tq

Comment: @JackPowell can u move this method to class which is extended by SqliteOpenHelper?

Answer (score 0):

Need to initialize DB before use of cursor;

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
//cursor usage for db
```

So your code should be like this:

```
public int FindInDatabase(String info){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT id FROM " + DatabaseName + " WHERE " + DataField + " = " + info,null);
        if (c != null){
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c.getInt(1);
    }
```